# Android TransactionTooLargeException when calling TakePicture

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Need to utilise the camera in my app for work, I see that things have changed in API >= 28 compared to how I used to do it where I could use startActivityForResult.

However I am facing a problem where I launch the camera app, and immediately get the 'TransactionTooLargeException' error message in the debug/run console.

For calling up the camera, I am doing

```
mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
            result -> {
                if (result) {

                }
            }
    );
```

Where mGetContent is defined in the class as

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> mGetContent;
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml file I have the following

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.test.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

In my file_paths file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="."/>
    <files-path
        name="app_images"
        path="./files/"/>
</paths>
```

I have a button set up in my activity where I launch the camera using

```
findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(v -> {
    File directory = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "app_images");
    if (!directory.exists()) directory.mkdir();

    File file = new File(directory, "image.jpg");

    Uri uri = getUriForFile(this, "com.test.fileprovider", file);

    mGetContent.launch(uri);
};
```

As soon as I tap on the button, and the camera app opens up, I get what I can only assume is an overly general error message.

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1284092)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test, PID: 14296
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1284092 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1284092 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:511)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4524)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
```

Been trying to Google search to find things, but having trouble nailing down what the actual issue is.

Some suggestions pointed me towards the onSaveInstanceState, so I override that and set a breakpoint on it to see what was happening, but it made it through without any issues (from what I could tell).

Kind of at a loss with this one.

Comment: The general cause of this is that the Bundle of an Intent can only be about 1 MB.  Above that this exception gets thrown.  This counts for bundles in SaveInstanceState, but also any intents in the app.  Based on timing, this was probably the intent to launch the camera, although it could have been onSaveInstanceState as well.

Comment: Is there an easy way to figure out which one exactly? Do I need to clear out existing intents somehow?

The Activity that calls the camera gets passed a few things via an intent, and unfortunately all of them are required because once the image has been taken, it needs to be sent off to a web service.

Comment: I just tried removing each extra from the intent passed to the activity, it unfortunately didn't fix my issue.

Really wish this error message was more helpful in trying to work out where the problem was.

I see there is a tool on Github, I did try that tool, but it didn't print out anything to logcat.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that you're 2 or 3 calls to the event loop away from where the intent was created by the time it crashes.  They really ought to check immediately to make it easier.  One thing you can do is replace onSaveInstanceState with a function that does NOT call super and does not add anything to the bundle, that would eliminate one avenue.

Comment: So I changed the override for onSaveInstanceState so that it clears the bundle and doesn't call the super. That stopped the error message from appearing. Sadly, when I take a photo using the camera, it isn't taking me back to my app at all, the camera app just remains active.

Comment: So not sure if that is related to me breaking how onSaveInstanceState works or maybe I'm calling the TakePicture wrong somehow. There's very little information out there (at least for Java) on how TakePicture actually works, most examples still just use the startActivityForResult.

Comment: Well, from the examples I see (I haven't used this API yet myself), launch() takes the mime type, not a uri.  Perhaps giving it the wrong type caused something with that, sucking in the contents of the uri.

Comment: It depends on how you created it. I created the ActivityResultLauncher with the object type set to 'Uri', which means launch() requires a uri. I'm almost thinking it might be easier to drop back an API level, or maybe I should move away from passing extras via Intents and using something else? What exactly makes up a bundle, out of my 3 activities (MainActivity which calls another activity which calls this activity), I pass very very little via the intents.

Comment: `TakePicture` (and anything that starts another activity) has no bearing on the size of your saved instance state or the exception you're getting. It sounds like you have something else in your app that is taking up an excessive amount of space. Have you looked at tools like [toolargetool](https://github.com/guardian/toolargetool)?

Comment: Yeah, that was the tool I looked at from Github. Followed the installation instructions (build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml), then created a new Application class and set it up in AndroidManifest.xml, overrode the onCreate method to have it start logging. However it never logged anything to logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wowsers as to what makes up the bundle in the onSaveInstanceState.

I have some imageviews, imagebuttons, and just general buttons in my app to make things easier for our staff.

I went through and changed the 'saveState' of all the ImageViews and ImageButtons from the default of true to false, since I don't care what state they were in, they are just visual guides.

Took the android:viewHierarchyState from 1.2MB down to 1.6KB, my Parcel size is now 3.3KB and it no longer crashes when suspending the app to bring up the camera app.

TooLargeTool was useful, but I couldn't make it work the way the Github page says, I told it to 'startLogging', and in my activity where the crash was happening, I set a breakpoint and checked if it was logging using 'isLogging' and it came back 'true'.

In the end I just had it log the output of `TooLargeTool.bundleBreakdown(outState)` in the onSaveInstanceState.

Thanks to Gabe Sechan and ianhanniballake for pointing me towards what it might be, there's not much out there on for this particular exception, I mean, there is, but it appears that it is different for everyone.

Really wish Google would print out a better set of error messages for it to make it easier to work out which activity was the problem (or in my case, all 3 activities combined).